# iOS 6 - Able to save .pdf from URL, able to display it in a WebView, NOT able to move it to iBooks

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction, xcode4.6

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. Get a .pdf from external URL
2. Save it into my local disk
3. Display it in a WebView
4. Allow the user to move the .pdf to another app who can read .pdf

Everything from 1 to 3 works fine. But nothing is moved/shared to/with other apps. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. This is what I'm doing.

**How I save the pdf in the Documents folder (viewDidLoad):**

```
// to save the pdf into local file system (tempString is the pdf url)
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] 
    initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:tempString]];
NSString *resourceToPath = [[NSString alloc] 
    initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]
    stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] 
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
NSString *filePAth = [resourceToPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];
[pdfData writeToFile:filePAth atomically:YES];

// to populate the WebView
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePAth];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
[my_web_view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
//[editoriale_view setDelegate:self];
[my_web_view loadRequest:requestObj];
```

**In my viewDidLoad() function I create a button to allow the user to open a list of apps who can read .pdf files:**

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self 
    action:@selector(show_Button)];
```

**And here's my show_Button function:**

```
-(void)show_Button {
    NSString *resourceToPath = [[NSString alloc] 
        initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] 
        stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] 
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
        NSString *filePAth = [resourceToPath 
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];

    NSLog(@"filePath = %@", filePAth);
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePAth];    
    NSLog(@"url2 = %@", url2);

    UIDocumentInteractionController *docContr = [UIDocumentInteractionController 
        interactionControllerWithURL:url2];
    [docContr presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
 }
```

When I try this on my device everything works fine until I tap on one of the icons in the list (i.e. the iBooks one). Then the app closes (it doesn't crash, it simply closes).

**Here's what the console prints for the two logs I put in the show_Button function:**

```
1. filePath = /Users/[MY_USER]/Library/Application Support/iPhone
    Simulator/6.1/Applications/[MY_EXAD_APP_ID]/Documents/myPDF.pdf
2. url2 = file://localhost/Users/[MY_USER]/Library/Application%20Support/
    iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/[MY_EXAD_APP_ID]/Documents/myPDF.pdf
```

Anyone wants to try to make me understand what I'm doing wrong? I'm using Xcode 4.6. I browsed my iPhone app file system with a third-party software and the file "MyPDF.pdf" actually IS in the Documents" folder, and that's clear because the WebView is correctly populated.

Comment: The way in which you construct the path to *Documents* looks dodgy.  What's wrong with simply using `[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]`?

Comment: @trojanfoe, thank you for your comment. I now build my "resourceToPath" variable like you said. This won't solve my problem tho, because even if I took a shortcut I arrived to the same finish line.

Comment: I think it might be because you haven't implement the `UIDocumentInteractionController` delegate, however the delegate method `documentInteractionController:canPerformAction:` is deprecated in iOS 6.0 and I cannot quickly find its replacement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had not implemented the UIDocumentenInteractionController delegate in the .h file. Now I have and everything works fine. Thank you to @trojanfoe for the useful hint.

Answer (score 0):

Change `CGRectZero` to self.view.bounds when you display the document controller.